# Error en update Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Deseo realizar una actualización de mis datos de una entidad cabecera (eReclamos) y detalle (eReclamosDetalle), en la capa de presentación valido mi detalle que esta ingresado en un datagridview, luego a traves de la capa de negocio verifico si el reclamo es nuevo llamo al metodo de Insert o Update segun el caso a continuacion mi codigo:

Presentacion

```
    public override void tsbSaveClick()
    {
        try
        {
            if (ValidarDatosAviso())
            {
                if (ValidarDatosFactura())
                {
                    LlenarEntidadAviso();
                    int numeroReclamo = NReclamos.Save(eReclamos);
                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Reclamo {0} registrado", numeroReclamo), "Reclamos", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    LlenarDataGridViewReclamos(eReclamos.CLI_CODIGO, 32);
                    tcReclamo.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    AdminGrupo(false, false, false);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Capa Negocio

```
    public static int Save(RECLAMOS eReclamos)
    {
        int numeroReclamo;
        if (eReclamos.RECL_NUMERO == 0)
        {
            numeroReclamo = DReclamos.Insert(eReclamos);
        }
        else
        {
            numeroReclamo = DReclamos.Update(eReclamos);
        }
        return numeroReclamo;
    }
```

Capa Datos

```
    public static int Update(RECLAMOS eReclamos)
    {
        int maxIdReclamoDetalle = 0;

        using (RSAEntities ctx = new RSAEntities())
        {
            //Cambio de estado para hacer Update de la cabecera
            ctx.Entry(eReclamos).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

            //Obtener MaxId en caso que haya nuevos registros para agregar al detalle
            maxIdReclamoDetalle = DReclamosDetalleAM.GetMaxId();

            foreach (RECLAMOS_DETALLE_AM eReclamoDetalle in eReclamos.RECLAMOS_DETALLE_AM)
            {
                //Si es un detalle Nuevo debe hacer Insert
                if (eReclamoDetalle.RECL_DETALLE_ID == 0)
                {
                    maxIdReclamoDetalle++;
                    eReclamoDetalle.RECL_DETALLE_ID = maxIdReclamoDetalle;
                    eReclamoDetalle.RECL_NUMERO = eReclamos.RECL_NUMERO;
                    ctx.RECLAMOS_DETALLE_AM.Add(eReclamoDetalle);
                }
                //Si ya existe solo debe hacer Update
                else
                {
                    ctx.Entry(eReclamoDetalle).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }

            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
        return eReclamos.RECL_NUMERO;
    }
```

Al ejecutar la linea que esta negrilla, me muestra el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A que se debe este error???

El problema lo tengo solo con el metodo Update, cuando inserto por primera vez cabecera/detalle funciona perfectamente

Desde ya les quedo agradecido por sus amables comentarios.

Saludos

Guivan,

Answer (score 0):

La unica manera que funcione fue esta:

```
    public static int Update(RECLAMOS eReclamos)
    {
        int maxIdReclamoDetalle = 0;

        using (RSAEntities ctx = new RSAEntities())
        {
            ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            eReclamos.CLIENTES = null;
            eReclamos.ASEGURADORAS = null;
            eReclamos.RAMOS = null;
            eReclamos.EJECUTIVOS = null;

            //Cambio de estado para hacer Update de la cabecera
            ctx.Entry(eReclamos).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;

            //Obtener MaxId en caso que haya nuevos registros para agregar al detalle
            maxIdReclamoDetalle = DReclamosDetalleAM.GetMaxId();

            foreach (RECLAMOS_DETALLE_AM eReclamoDetalle in eReclamos.RECLAMOS_DETALLE_AM)
            {
                //Si es un detalle Nuevo debe hacer Insert
                if (eReclamoDetalle.RECL_DETALLE_ID == 0)
                {
                    maxIdReclamoDetalle++;
                    eReclamoDetalle.RECL_DETALLE_ID = maxIdReclamoDetalle;
                    eReclamoDetalle.RECL_NUMERO = eReclamos.RECL_NUMERO;
                    ctx.Entry(eReclamoDetalle).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
                }
                //Si ya existe solo debe hacer Update
                else
                {
                    ctx.Entry(eReclamoDetalle).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }

            //ctx.Entry<CLIENTES>(eReclamos.CLIENTES).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
            //ctx.Entry<ASEGURADORAS>(eReclamos.ASEGURADORAS).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
            //ctx.Entry<RAMOS>(eReclamos.RAMOS).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
            //ctx.Entry<EJECUTIVOS>(eReclamos.EJECUTIVOS).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;

            ctx.Entry(eReclamos).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
        return eReclamos.RECL_NUMERO;
    }
```

Sin embargo, el codigo que esta comentariado no me funciona, se supone que debo hacer uso del estado detach o unchanged ya que las entidades de navegacion como ASEGURADORAS, RAMOS, CLIENTES y EJECUTIVOS no cambio propiedad alguno pero de todas formas lo requiero para mostrar en la interface del usuario.

Saludos 
Guivan

Comment: Hola.. podrias comentarnos si sos el mismo usuario y perdiste tu acceso a la cuenta que pregunta? responder tus propias preguntas es perfectamente valido y si este es el caso, que lo hagas con el mismo usuario es todavia mucho mejor.

Comment: Si soy el mismo usuario.

Comment: Perdiste acceso a tu cuenta original? podemos ayudarte a juntar las mismas de ser necesario.